# Element Width Value Range isn't working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target an init script (alert for now) to fire if a wrapper element is within a certain range using jQuery. I've tried everything I can think of and am now in need of the communities assistance which i will be eternally grateful.

When I run the fiddle and the div element is 600px, I get an alert that states 600 from the `alert(elementSize);`then I get a second alert from the `alert("laptop and desktop");` which is incorrect as the correct alert should be 'tablet'.

```
  var elementSize = $("#outerWrapper").width();
  alert(elementSize);
  if ($(elementSize >= 801) && (elementSize <= 990)) {
    alert("laptop and desktop");
  } else if ($(elementSize >= 600) && (elementSize <= 800)) {
    alert("tablet");
  } else {
    alert("neither");
  }
```

I've also tried this:

```
 if ($(elementSize >= 801 && elementSize <= 990)) {
    alert("laptop and desktop");
 } else if ($(elementSize >= 600 && elementSize <= 800)) {
    alert("tablet");
 } else {
    alert("neither");
 }
```

Anyway, here's a public fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/timhjellum/k8vaofrz/

Comment: What are you expecting to see, vs. what you *do* see? And does that problem go away when you remove the extra `$`s in your `if`s? That is, just `if ((elementSize >= 801) && (elementSize <= 990)) {` and `else if ((elementSize >= 600) && (elementSize <= 800)) {`?

Comment: (seems so: https://jsfiddle.net/k8vaofrz/136/)

Comment: The problem in a nutshell -> https://jsfiddle.net/tf0w6uLd/

Answer (score 0):

Duh, Fixed! Removed the jquery $ which is not needed. Updated the fiddle too.

```
function checkSize() {
  var elementSize = $("#outerWrapper").width();
  alert(elementSize);
  if ((elementSize >= 801) && (elementSize <= 990)) {
    alert("laptop and desktop");
  } else if ((elementSize >= 600) && (elementSize <= 800)) {
    alert("tablet");
  } else {
    alert("neither");
  }
}
```